# Pass down master page object to nested master page

Tags: c#, webforms

Apologies if this is too trivial but I seem to be running into an issue where I cannot access an object from a nested master page.

I'm having trouble passing down a User object from my main master to my nested master. By the time it gets to my nested master page it's null. I don't ever remember having trouble getting master pages talking but in this instance it just doesn't want to work.

So the set up, Some code omitted:

```
public partial class RWCMSMain : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public Business.BusinessEntities.User LoggedOnUser { get;  set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Get the user
       var loggedOnUser = userRepo.GetUser(securityToken);

       //Now set the property
       this.LoggedOnUser = loggedOnUser;
    }
}
```

If I was to access this from a content page that inherits the main master all is great but the idea was to have a master page that contains side bar.

Now my side.master inherits from main master:

```
public partial class RWCMSSide : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
   //Create property for nested master
    public Business.BusinessEntities.User LoggedOnUser { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Assign main masters user to the new property
       //Master.LoggedOnUser is always null
       this.LoggedOnUser = Master.LoggedOnUser;
    }
}
```

You could argue that I could recreate the user on the nested master page but then that would create two hits to the database when it could be done as one.

Whilst debugging the main master the user exists, it's just not being passed down.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

The Master's `Load` is executed [**after**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3(v=vs.140).aspx) the Child's `Load`:

> - ...
> - Master page Init event.
> - Content page Init event.
> - Content page Load event.
> - Master page Load event.
> - Master page controls Load event.
> - ...

That's is why the property is null.

## Solution

**1.** You can set it in the `Init` event - `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)...` if it is not dependent on the page being loaded (as it is probably).

**2.**  Or you can turn the property into the lazy property(no need for actual `Lazy<T>` if it is not (and it probably should not be) intended to be used in multithreaded code):

```
public partial class RWCMSMain : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private Business.BusinessEntities.User m_LoggedOnUse;

    public Business.BusinessEntities.User LoggedOnUser 
    { 
         get
         {
              if (this.m_LoggedOnUse == null)
                  this.m_LoggedOnUse = userRepo.GetUser(securityToken);

              return this.m_LoggedOnUse;
         } 
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Good find. I don't know how I missed that. I was fixated on the code it's self. Just need to find a work around. I'll look into the life cycle. Great work!